# Running python script on linux at startup just not working

Tags: python, linux, startup

EDIT: It turns out that because the script is supposed to take a screenshot, it cant because it starts too early. I thought that it was not the script having problems because it worked fine not on startup.

I am trying to run a python script on startup on linux on a RPi-4. I have tried adding it to rc.local as

```
/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py &
```

When I rebooted, nothing happened. I also tried to put it in crontab:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py &
```

Still nothing happened. I have this line at the start of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

The script definitely runs without any problems just calling it normally through terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that the script ran and ended?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly means "that didn't work". What happens and what do you expect to happen? What happens when you run it manually. Maybe you have to show the code.

Comment: And redirecting output to a log file would be helpful to figure out what’s going on  python3 /path/to/script.py >/tmp/script.log 2>&1

Comment: @CristiFati It should run in an infinite loop

Comment: @NicholasRees That helped. It turns out that the script can't take a screenshot that early.

Answer (score 0):

use full path to python3.

something like

`@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py &`

Comment: Sadly, it still didn't work